# JavaScript - Push string to object conditionally

Tags: javascript

I would like to conditionally push `item.description`, which is basically a string, into an object.

Basically, I have two input fields where the user is required to enter pickup and dropoff location. I take these two addresses and I push them in an array so I can retrieve them in another method. For that, I have the below code:

```
chooseItem(item) {
  this.pickAndDropLocationArray = {};

  if (this.lastFocusedName == 'dropOff') {
    this.pickAndDropLocationArray.dropOff = item.description
  } else if (this.lastFocusedName == 'pickUp') {
  this.pickAndDropLocationArray.pickUp = item.description
 }
}
```

Expected output:

```
 {"pickUp":"locationName","dropOff":"locationName"}
```

The issue, however, is that if it pushes droppoff on the object, it automatically deletes pickup from the object, which is pretty logical based on the code written. I am out of ideas and I don't know how to sort it out.

Comment: You keep entirely overwriting `this.pickAndDropLocationArray = {};`. That's why things appear to be "deleted". Also, it's an object, not an array.

Comment: you need it to be an array or object? a bit confused.

Comment: as canon points out, don't reset `this.pickAndDropLocationArray` inside the function

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are overriding the object each time it is called. If it needs to be initialized, than you need to check for its existence before overriding it.

this.pickAndDropLocationArray = {};

should be

```
this.pickAndDropLocationArray = this.pickAndDropLocationArray || {};
```

or a truthy check

```
if (!this.pickAndDropLocationArray) {
    this.pickAndDropLocationArray = {}; 
}
```

so to clean up the code

```
function chooseItem(item) {
  this.pickAndDropLocationArray = this.pickAndDropLocationArray || {};
  this.pickAndDropLocationArray[this.lastFocusedName] = item.description
}
```